# How to put elements from NSMutableArray into C char?

Tags: objective-c, c, nsmutablearray, char

I have a NSMutableArray and I need to sort its elements into separate C char.

How to accomplish that? Or is it better to put the elements into NSStrings?

I've tried this, and it crashes when I try to log the result:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

... do something to fill the array ...

NSString *string;

string = [array objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"String: %@", string);
```

**I really prefer putting the elements of the array into C char, because I already have some woking code using char instead of NSStrin**g.

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain, so is `array` full of `NSString`s and you want an array of `const char *` to sort, or do you actually want a single `C` `char` from the strings in your `array` or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont see any specific reason to convert `NSString` to C chars. To sort an array full of `NSStrings` try this method -

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSString *string = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"String: %@", string);
```

Comment: I receive the warning "Semantic Issue: Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableArray *' from 'NSArray *'"

Comment: @Winston both arrays `sortedArray` & `array` have to be of the same type `NSMutableArray` or `NSArray`. Change that & i dont see a reason for this to not work...

Comment: I verified that and I only have NSMutableArray. When I "Jump to Definition" on xCode for sortedArrayUsingSelector I get: "- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingSelector:(SEL)comparator;"